# Android, how to get last start session and end session of any application in a device?

Tags: android

Hi Im trying to create an application that will compute for the usages of each app in a device. How can I get the start session and the end session for an application.

Comment: Explain what you think a 'session' is with respect to the Android Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: http://www.google.com/analytics/ might be useful tool for you to use

Comment: I cant use analytics in other application. I want to get the sessions of the other applications not mine.